# Github ImageSlideShow library implementation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, slider, slideshow

I recently downloaded an image slider from https://github.com/zvonicek/ImageSlideshow

I have never used it previously. Can somebody please tell me how to use it? Do i have to link it to imageView somehow or to something else? Any help will be appreciated. I didn't find any layman tutorial online.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's so simple. You cannot link imageview to imageslideshow. But what you should do is to use View(look for view in object library on bottom right of Xcode). Click on that view and drag it to storyboard where you want. With this selected, go to identity inspector and set class to "ImageSlideshow" without quotes. Make sure you have installed ImageSlideShow properly so that class is visible there.

Comment: i love stackoverflow. Got a quick reply. Thanks a lot. I am trying this. I will comment if i face any issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks @Zohaib. It worked. :)

Comment: Thanks dude worked for me:)